# How do I (de)serialize a list of type that requires a custom JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, json, xna, json.net

I have a class that needs serializing/deserializing. It looks like this:

```
public class Animation
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly string name;

    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly IList<Rectangle> frames;
}
```

However, Json.Net doesn't play nice with XNA's `Rectangle` class. It needs a custom `JsonConverter`, which I [managed to scrape together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359362/1015595). This works fine on classes with a single `Rectangle` property, like:

```
public class Sprite
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(RectangleConverter))]
    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly Rectangle frame;
}
```

But how do I apply that converter to the list of `Rectangle`s in my `Animation` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Comment: I saw that but I don't think he's trying to do the same thing. I am able to serialize/deserialize lists of base classes without a hitch, except for this particular class that requires a custom converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx), the XNA [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx) struct is marked as having a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and by default type converters [always return true when asked to convert to string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1155ebw.aspx).  Because of this Json.Net will by default try to create a string contract instead of an object contract, which will lead to an error when used with your RectangleConverter.  This can be fixed by using a custom `ContractResolver` to tell Json.Net that `Rectangle` should be treated as an object, not a string.  We can also set the converter inside the resolver, so you do not need to decorate your class properties with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute wherever you use a `Rectangle`.

Here is the code you would need:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(Rectangle) || objectType == typeof(Rectangle?))
        {
            JsonContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            contract.Converter = new RectangleConverter();
            return contract;
        }
        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}
```

To use the resolver, add it to the serializer settings and pass that to `DeserializeObject()` or `SerializeObject()` like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();

Animation anim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animation>(json, settings);
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON?

Comment: { "name": "moveleft", "frames": [ { "x": 0, "y": 128, "width": 64, "height": 64 }, { "x": 128, "y": 128, "width": 64, "height": 64 } ] }

Comment: It's specifically a problem with XNA's `Rectangle` - see the link I included in my original post.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the XNA Rectangle is convertible to string.  That may be the issue here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48011/discussion-between-davidkennedy85-and-brian-rogers)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone comes up with a better solution for me (there's got to be one), but this is working for me right now:

```
public class RectangleListConverter : RectangleConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var rectangleList = (IList<Rectangle>)value;

        var jArray = new JArray();

        foreach ( var rectangle in rectangleList )
        {
            jArray.Add( GetObject( rectangle ) );
        }

        jArray.WriteTo( writer );
    }

    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>();

        var jArray = JArray.Load( reader );

        foreach ( var jToken in jArray )
        {
            rectangleList.Add( GetRectangle( jToken ) );
        }

        return rectangleList;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I had to modify the `RectangleConverter` I was using:

```
public class RectangleConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var rectangle = (Rectangle)value;

        var jObject = GetObject( rectangle );

        jObject.WriteTo( writer );
    }

    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load( reader );

        return GetRectangle( jObject );
    }

    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected static JObject GetObject( Rectangle rectangle )
    {
        var x = rectangle.X;
        var y = rectangle.Y;
        var width = rectangle.Width;
        var height = rectangle.Height;

        return JObject.FromObject( new { x, y, width, height } );
    }

    protected static Rectangle GetRectangle( JObject jObject )
    {
        var x = GetTokenValue( jObject, "x" ) ?? 0;
        var y = GetTokenValue( jObject, "y" ) ?? 0;
        var width = GetTokenValue( jObject, "width" ) ?? 0;
        var height = GetTokenValue( jObject, "height" ) ?? 0;

        return new Rectangle( x, y, width, height );
    }

    protected static Rectangle GetRectangle( JToken jToken )
    {
        var jObject = JObject.FromObject( jToken );

        return GetRectangle( jObject );
    }

    protected static int? GetTokenValue( JObject jObject, string tokenName )
    {
        JToken jToken;
        return jObject.TryGetValue( tokenName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, out jToken ) ? (int)jToken : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

Animation class with new `JsonConverter` attribute:

```
public class Animation
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly string name;

    [JsonConverter(typeof(RectangleListConverter))]
    [JsonProperty]
    private readonly IList<Rectangle> frames;
}
```